# Getting the Highest value (probability) location from Opencv Mlp Response

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, neural-network

I am getting a response from my openCV NN in the output layer.. however minMaxLoc does not appear to be giving me the correct location of the highest value.. for example it may return {0.1028233, 0.1823877, 0.993834} and minMaxLoc will return the value 0 or 1, which is clearly not the highest value... is there a better way of finding this?

my MinMaxLoc Code is as follows- `cv::MinMaxLoc(Result,0,0,&max_loc,0);`

I then proceed to use max_loc.x value in a switch case.. which as said afore is incorrect..

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So upon further reading of the opencv data it turns out the newer version (2.4+) changes min and max location, so my 4th value where I store max_loc is actually the minimum location value, A simple change to `MinMaxLoc(Result,0,0,0,&max_loc);` Fixed this.

For future reference MinMaxLoc works as follows:

```
MinMaxLoc(inputValue,ReturnValOfMin#,ReturnValOfMax#,MinValLocation,MaxValLocation);
```

the values you do not need you can leave as 0, as I did.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to mention it. You can verify this answer and thus close it